# R Internationalization and environment

Tags: r

I'm using R 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't quite understand [internationalization](https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Internationalization)

```
> Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "en_US")
> 2+x
Error: object 'x' not found
> Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "fr_FR")
> 2+x
Erreur : objet 'x' introuvable
> Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "en_US")
> 2+x
Erreur : objet 'x' introuvable
```

More specifically, I don't understand why the last error message is printed in French. Even more strange, the other error messages are displayed in English. For instance:

```
> log(-1)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In log(-1) : NaNs produced
```

And when I do the same trick (`Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "fr_FR")` and then `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE" = "en_US")`), the message is displayed in French.

Why can't I get the messages to get back to English, and is there any workaround?

Comment: This happens just in RStudio?

Comment: No, not only in RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
options(tz="Europe/Stockholm")
```

and/or

```
Sys.setenv(TZ="Europe/Stockholm")
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

If you want you settings to persist add those to you .Rprofile like so:

```
.First <- function(){
    options(tz="Europe/Stockholm") #Your tz
    Sys.setenv(TZ="Europe/Stockholm") #Your tz
}
```

Clean .Rdata and restart

Comment: Thank you @Aleh. That worked for me. Actually, timezone was not necessary.